# Docker swarm manager cannot recognize swarm nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I follow these steps to create Docker swarm cluster.

First: Create Cunsol

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox mh-keystore  
eval "$(docker-machine env mh-keystore)"  
docker run -d \  
 -p "8500:8500" \  
 -h "consul" \  
 progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

Second: Create swarm manager

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox node1  
docker run -d -p 4000:4000 swarm manage -H :4000 --replication --  advertise $(docker-machine ip node1):4000 consul://$(docker-machine ip mh-keystore):8500
```

Third: Create swarm node

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox node2  
docker run -d swarm join --advertise=$(docker-machine ip node2):2375   consul://$(docker-machine ip mh-keystore):8500
```

Fourth: Login to node1

```
docker-machine ssh node1  
docker -H :4000 info
```

But this instruction output

> (unknown): 192.168.99.106:2375(node2 ip)
>     └ ID:
>     └ Status: Pending
>     └ Containers: 0
>     └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 0
>     └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 0 B
>     └ Labels:
>     └ Error: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon   running on this host?....

How can I fix this ?
I have already checked node2 and it runs well.

---

**[Update]** I follow [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/) and it works well. But I still wan't to know how set up swarm cluster without docker-machine.

---

**[Update]** Another approach doen't work either.

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
 --swarm \
 --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip mh-keystore):8500" \
 --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip mh-keystore):8500" \
 --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" \
 mhs-demo1
```

Node1 docker info appear mhs-demo1 ip but info still unknown..

---

**[Update]**
When I type eval `docker-machine env --swarm node1` It shows

> Error checking TLS connection: "node1" is not a swarm master. The
>   --swarm flag is intended for use with swarm masters Does this cause error ? Why using swarm manager instruction to set up is not swarm
>   master?

It's so strange. How can I get the same result as

```
docker-machine create \ -d virtualbox \ --swarm --swarm-master \ 
 --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip mh-keystore):8500" \ 
 --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip mh-keystore):8500" \ 
 --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" \
 mhs-demo0
```

using swarm instruction?

I want to use swarm instruction because I don't want to declare swarm master when I create it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using docker-machine just to start a node? You can use docker machine to setup your node with swarm ready to go..
You can follow this tutorial
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/

Comment: Yes. I know this methods.  But I just want to figure out why another approach doesn't work .......

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting this file with:

```
sudo rm /etc/docker/key.json
```

Then restart docker with:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

At this point docker will make a new key.json file and your master should be able to find your workers.  This happens sometimes when you use the same image for all your worker nodes, but its an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

In docker 1.12 swarm mode is directly available. There is no need for a key value store for the cluster.

just follow the this : https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/